Excel TEXTJOIN of non empty rows in a table
I have a table named "Table1" and a column named "Details".
I would like help with joining the text in column Details into one cell with a linebreak separator - CHAR(10), I would also like to avoid empty rows and rows that contain the substring "FRUIT" and place the value on the first row that is not empty in each "session". I shared an image to better understand


What's better: avoid unneeded information in the result or delete it afterwards? :-)

always avoid. never destructive act :) the solution by Chat GPT I shared with slight modifications did the trick

Here is one way of achieving the desired output. However, it is not as elegant as it could be, but it does the job as expected:


• Formula used in cell B2
=LET(
     a, SCAN(0,[Details]="",LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,x))),
     b, MAP(a, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER([Details],x=a,"")))),
     d, XLOOKUP(COUNTIF(Table12[[#Headers],[Details]]:[@Details],""),a,b,""),
     IF(IFNA(TEXTBEFORE(d,CHAR(10)),d)=[@Details],d,""))




=LET(
     _a,SCAN(,TableK[Details],LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISERR(FIND(":",y)),x,y))),
     REDUCE("Result",UNIQUE(_a),LAMBDA(u,v,
     LET(z,FILTER(TableK[Details],_a=v),VSTACK(u,EXPAND(VSTACK("",
     TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,DROP(z,1))),ROWS(z),1,""))))))


• For Structured References:
=LET(
     a, [Details],
     b, SCAN(,a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISERR(FIND(":",y)),x,y))),
     c, TOCOL(ROW(a)/FIND(":",a)^0,3),
     IFNA(IF(MATCH(ROW([@Details]),c+1,),TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,
     DROP(FILTER(a,LOOKUP(ROW([@Details]),c,UNIQUE(b))=b),1))),""))



What if I wanted in addition to empty cells also avoid also cells in the column "Details" that contain the substring FRUIT, please see edited question

@Kobe2424 you first thank the person who was kind enough here to answer the question you posted by accepting the answer. Then you go post a new question in a correct method. Editing questions is uncool after people put in work. Also consider the likelihood of success going the edit route vs. accept: if you accept, and post new question, MB is likely going to inspired to help you again. Editing a post... meh.... good luck.

@pgSystemTester You're right I didn't mean to be rude, I'll do that.

@Kobe2424 good job. I worked with Kobe Bryant a couple times at UCI track. #Facts.

I found an answer with the help of Chat GPT and some modifications I did, might help someone else, here it is:
=IF(AND([@Details]<>"", LEFT([@Details], 6)<>"FRUIT:"),
IF(OR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN([Details])))="", LEFT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN([Details]))), 6)="FRUIT:"),
    TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, [@Details]:INDEX([@Details]:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(50000,COLUMN([Details]))), MATCH(1, (INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1,COLUMN([Details]))):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(50000,COLUMN([Details])))="")+(LEFT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()+1,COLUMN([Details]))):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(50000,COLUMN([Details]))), 6)="FRUIT:"), 0))),
    ""),
"")

